# AWS Guide on Route 53, VirtualHost and website in document root

Tags: amazon-ec2, virtualhost, amazon-route53

I have researched this topic for one week!

My situation is as follows:

1. I have an instance, already set up with an elastic IP address (e.g. 5.6.7.9)
2. I have a website in my document root folder (e.g. var/www/html/website_folder/index.html)
3. I have purchased and registered a domain name from AWS itself (e.g. mywebsite.com)
4. I have created a hosted zone for this (mywebsite.com) website, it automatically generated two record sets - NS and SOA. I have read numerous articles on CNAME and A records with VirtualHost configurations and none seem to work.
5. My security configuration allows all sources - 0.0.0.0/0 for http, TCP...
6. An example of what i tried:

   *.mywebsite.com CNAME (value = mywebsite.com)

I could not add A record because ip address for website is   5.6.7.9/website_folder which cannot be entered in the field provided

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80> 

ServerName mywebsite.com 
DocumentRoot var/www/html/website_folder
ServerAlias *.mywebsite.com

</VirtualHost>
```

This did not work. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

The settings were as follows:

1. In route 53

   - add A type with your instance elastic ip (e.g mywebsite.com A 5.6.7.9)
   - add CNAME e.g. (*.mywebsite.com CNAME mywebsite.com)
   - add CNAME e.g. (@.mywebsite.com CNAME 5.6.7.9/website_folder)
2. In /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf add the following lines where it has "NameVirtualHost *:80"....at the bottom of the file:

`<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias www.mywebsite.com *.mywebsite.com
    DocumentRoot var/www/html/website_folder
</VirtualHost>`